# Is it possible to start Opera in Kiosk Mode without command line switches?

Tags: command-line, opera, command-line-arguments, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to setup Opera to run in Kiosk Mode without using any command line switches on Windows XP.

Originally I had it working by using a desktop shortcut with about 5 or 6 command line switches tagged on the end of the path to the opera.exe such as: **"C:\Program Files\Opera\opera.exe" -kioskmode -kioskresetstation -nocontextmenu -nodownload -nokeys** etc...

However, the kiosk system that it will be running on cannot startup and monitor Opera at all when there are additional command line switches being used, so I need to find an alternative way to do this.

I've read the main kiosk mode docs on this and searched the Opera forums but can't find anything about setting this up without the command line switches. Ideally it would be great if there was a way to changes some settings in the **operaprefs.ini** config file to make it startup in kiosk mode by default when you just double click opera.exe.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Any help or advice on how to do this would be brilliant, thanks for reading...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not currently possible. You can always file a bug on https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ explaining the problem and requesting an INI setting. For now it seems you will need a workaround though..

Would it help to write a script that runs Opera with the right parameters and basically waits for the launched process to finish?